# What do you call decorated cloth?

Tags: word-request

What do you call decorated cloth? I am referring to the cloth that have decoration on them meaning they don't have a smooth texture, but have decorated parts that budges out of the fabric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the texture is created as part of the weaving process, [figured fabric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Figured_fabrics) or [loom-figured fabric](http://www.fabricdictionary.com/loom-figured-fabrics/344/loom-figured-fabrics.html).

> [Damask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damask) is a reversible figured fabric of silk, wool, linen, cotton, or
> synthetic fibers, with a pattern formed by weaving.

If the decoration is applied by stitching, appliqué or some other technique.

> [Appliqué](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliqu%C3%A9) is ornamental needlework in which pieces or patch of fabric
> in different shapes and patterns are sewn or stuck onto a larger piece
> to form a picture or pattern.